# Increasing setTimeout interval in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So I have a completely basic html file.
What I would like to do is to pick a random number 0-100 with the interval increasing each run through, the way I wanted it done was to have a for loop go through executing the code each time it's ran so the setTimeout increases the delay each time. What I wind up with is a very fast run through with the same delay all throughout.
My code that might explain a bit further is as follows:

```
for ( i = 0; i < Math.floor( Math.random() * 2000 ); i+=100 ) { 
  setTimeout( () => { 
    document.body.innerHTML = ( Math.random() * 101 );
  }, i );
}
```

The reason I want it done like this is so the code does eventually have a stopping point.

Comment: I think recursion would be the best way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop doesn't seem to reflect what you want to do.

You initialize `i` to 0

While `i` is less than (a random number less than 2000)

Set time out to `i` milliseconds (0, 100, 200, 300...)

Add 100 to `i`.

Try this:

```
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000)
let counter = 10 // number of times to run
for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
  setTimeOut (() => {
    // Do something
  }, random)
  let random += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000)
}
```

Comment: This one surprisingly worked to the extent I wanted it to. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> Undeclared variables are always global

Declare the variable `i` with [**`let`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), this will create a block scoped local variable and will retain the current iteration value in the function:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor( Math.random() * 2000 ); i+=100 ) { 
  setTimeout( () => { 
    //document.body.innerHTML += ( Math.random() * 101 );
    console.log(i);
  }, i );
}
```